# No se puede importar HttpServlet en IntelliJ Ultimate con JavaEE

Tags: java, java-ee, intellij-idea

estoy intentando crear una aplicación con JavaEE en IntelliJ Ultimate. El plugin viene por defecto y está activado, pero a la hora de importar

```
import javax.servlet.*
```

no me aparece la biblioteca, ¿alguien conoce alguna solución? Gracias.

Comment: ¿Tienes añadidas a tu proyecto las bibliotecas de Glassfish?

Comment: No las tengo añadidas, ¿hace falta realmente?

Comment: En base a mi experiencia, esos paquetes vienen en la libreria de Glassfish.